# how to get/set custom attribute values of/from html controls through JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have three text boxes and one button control.The first two text boxes have two values and on click of the button the third text box will be populated with some value using the first 2 text box values.
this is how they render at browser:

```
<input name="20152" class="valid-decimal" id="20152"  type="text" maxlength="4000" placeholder="" value="" data-fieldname="Height">
<input name="20153" class="valid-decimal" id="20152"  type="text" maxlength="4000" placeholder="" value="" data-fieldname="Weight">
<input name="20155" id="testcompute" type="text" maxlength="4000" data-fieldname="BMI" placeholder="Result">
var formula="{10 * (Height + Weight) }";
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" onclick="javascript: FillAndSubmit(formula);" type="submit">Calculate</button>
```

Now , onclick of the button when I call the FillAndSubmit(formula);I need to get the values from the text boxes using the data-fieldname property and after doing some calculation will have to set the calculated value on the third text box by identifying its  data-fieldname="BMI".
I think its very easy in JQuery,any help will be great!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you need something like this,

```js
function FillAndSubmit() {
  var w = $("input[data-fieldname='Weight']").val();
  var h = $("input[data-fieldname='Height']").val();
  $("input[data-fieldname='BMI']").val(10 * (parseInt(h) + parseInt(w)));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="20152" class="valid-decimal" id="20152" type="text" maxlength="4000" placeholder="" value="" data-fieldname="Height">
<input name="20153" class="valid-decimal" id="20152" type="text" maxlength="4000" placeholder="" value="" data-fieldname="Weight">
<input name="20155" id="testcompute" type="text" maxlength="4000" data-fieldname="BMI" placeholder="Result">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" onclick="FillAndSubmit()" type="submit">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find an element by attributes like this

```
$("input[data-fieldname='BMI']").val(10);
```